# Implementing Explicit algorithms vs built-in methods eg: Sorting in c# or any other language

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

This is a general question as to **where and why** we need to implement customized algorithms when some algorithms are already being served as methods in certain languages. 
For Example: Would implementing a custom sorting algorithm in C# be more efficient than using the built-in sort() method? 
 Wouldn't the customized algorithm add overhead to the pre-existing code?

Comment: well, if yours was faster, yes.  If not, no.  I don't know what else you mean.

Comment: Built-in methods aren't magic. They're just code that someone already wrote. If you know a significantly more efficient (for your particular scenario) algorithm than the built-in method, there's no reason you wouldn't implement it.

Comment: The questions is way open-ended for SO in my opinion. Are you talking about abstract performance (like O(n^2) vs. O(n)), or about performance on concrete data/machine, or about developer efficiency, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are sometimes circumstances where you know more about the expected data that you're going to run into, and so you can fine-tune an algorithm based on that knowledge to produce something measurably better than the general algorithms that are provided with your framework.

For example, let's say that you're sorting a list of strings, but in your specific application the strings are all going to be composed of a broad spread of lowercase letters, from `a` through `z`. You could probably get really good performance by indexing each of the strings, dropping them into positions in an array based on the values of their first character or two, and then only using a traditional sorting algorithm on the few array indexes that have more than one item in them. There are other, more complicated algorithms that could provide even better performance in cases like this as well.

As a general rule of thumb, though, you should use what you're given unless you detect a measurable performance issue that you need to address. The built-in algorithms were chosen to have "good enough" performance in almost every situation.